# UNIX child's process group id

Tags: unix, process, fork

After fork(), what is the child's process group id if no explicit `setpgid` is called by any process?

I search the web(do some tests myself), it seems it is the process group id of the parent. But where can I find the standard file that mentions this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The child inherits its parent's process group.

This is POSIX standard behavior, mentioned in the [definition of a "process group"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_296):

> 3.296 Process Group
>
> A collection of processes that permits the signaling of related processes. Each process in the system is a member of a process group that is identified by a process group ID. *A newly created process joins the process group of its creator.*

(emphasis added)

The behavior is also implied by the [POSIX specification of `fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), which, after describing many process attributes that are *not* inherited by child processes, clarifies that "[a]ll other process characteristics defined by POSIX.1-2008 shall be the same in the parent and child processes."